# amCharts Radar is not responsive

Tags: amcharts, radar-chart

Though I have included responsive js & enabled responsive property to true, Radar chart is not responsive. Even on their site, it is not responsive for mobile view.

What should I do?

```
 <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

This is my script :

```
 <script>
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", {
      "type": "radar",
      "dataProvider": [{
        "country": "Czech Republic",
        "litres": 156.9
      }, {
        "country": "Ireland",
        "litres": 131.1
      }],
      "categoryField": "country",
      "startDuration": 2,
      "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0.15,
        "minimum": 0,
        "dashLength": 3,
        "axisTitleOffset": 20,
        "gridCount": 5
      }],
      "graphs": [{
        "valueField": "litres",
        "title": "Litres",
        "bullet": "round",
        "balloonText": "[[value]] litres of beer per year"
      }],
      "legend": {},
      "responsive": {
        "enabled": true
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radar chart **is** supported by Responsive plugin. (on amcharts.com responsive features are not enabled for demos, so it's not a good test)

Take for instance this chart:

[image]

Live: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/64459eb6a0041d071b0db44594b2f95a

By default, Responsive plugin removes legend at 550px or less:

[image]

By ~300px it starts removing labels on axes:

[image]

You can override default responsive rules or implement your own set as it is [described here](https://github.com/amcharts/responsive#rules).

Just make sure that you include `responsive.min.js` on your web page, i.e.:

```
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I checked the link you gave but it does not remove labels for mobile view.

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile" view? If you are viewing the chart on iPhone it doesn't mean it needs to kick in. Responsive features kick in at certain resolutions. Try resizing the window.